# Select data in a pop up window and send that value to home page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to web-app and Spring MVC. I run into one situation and can't solve it.

I have a JSP form with button. When click this button it will open a popup window contain a table list of Employee Code and Employee Name (select * from database). When the user select one of this Employee Code, I want it to send this value to my main JSP form.

I don't know how to do binding data what row that users select and send to the controller

Comment: sounds like a javascript generated popup, which has nothing to do with java/jsp. if it generates a completely new page, then you either have to trigger the main page (using javascript) to reload, after posting data from the popup, or do something else. I think this is likely something you just do clientside though, hence my first line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing this without a popup, ie just use the main window. Most browsers block popups these days, and it won't work without javascript. You'll need to figure out how to save state between requests though.

You can name the main window in javascript (`window.name = 'x'`) and set the popup form's `target` to that name. That will submit the form to the main window. Then use window.close() in the popup to close it.

Comment: In main page i'm using javascript (window.open to employee list window). My problem now is how can I bind value that user selected and send back to controller to show in main page